# (Google sheets script) How to add a value for the whole column at regular intervals

Tags: google-apps-script, refresh, calculated-columns

I'm new in this service useful for those like me that is not practical in the scripts of google. I'm looking for all-in-one google script for solve 2 problems:

1) I have in the following google sheet a table where every value in the "H" field, should be corrected adding the number 24 to each row, so as to have the value 42 instead of 19 in the column "H".

```
  ---example of table that I have now:
  id      hour              H   T   C   M   Q
  87      10/04/2018 15:11  18  19  430 19  38

  ---example of table that I want:
  id      hour              H   T   C   M   Q
  87      10/04/2018 15:11  42  19  430 19  38
```

2) My table refresh enterelly every 1 minute, so i need to re-add the number 24 to the "H" column every 1 minute.

Thanks to those who will take the time to help me!

Comment: I think the fastest trigger allowed these days is every 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
function add24toH(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Foglio1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    vA[i][2]+=24;//H
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

You can lookup all of the methods [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your support! I tried your code, but does not work, should I insert the id sheet somewhere? I have the yellow popup "Running the add24toH function..." but nothing happens

Comment: Very often new code requires some modification and debugging.  This is a start.  Now it's time for you to carry your own torch.  You'll need to add a timebased trigger and figure out why this code is not working for you.

Comment: With this code I solved the 2nd problem, the auto-sorting of the table:

Comment: function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var sheetNames = ["Foglio1"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
  });
}

Comment: For the 1° problem I need your help to find a way

Comment: this is a demo of the structure of my file [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cwAZj91Ge7EojBD8qp7FTb54OTmRjnBytQ_2wgYv2II/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It looks like the current function should work okay on the spreadsheet sample.

Comment: Can you add to your example some comments to understand how custominzing it? , maybe I'm writing something wrong, thnx

Comment: Have you tried looking up these methods in the Apps Script Reference document?

Comment: yes I'm studyng in the App reference document, now I want retry

Comment: I just tested the function on a sample sheet of mine that has numbers in column C and it works just fine.

Comment: Yeesss!! Great, works! But now I have another problem...how to make this two script in one? Because first my table should be sorted and after +24

Comment: It might be helpful if you would show us both of your scripts.

Comment: I entered the codes as an answer so that they are useful to many people

Answer (score 0):

All my script are 3: with the first we import a .csv file inside the google sheets, with the 2nd one we sort the table, and with the 3rd one we add +24 to the "H" column. So now i post the script:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("*.csv").next();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, 
csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}

function AutoSortOnEdit() {
var sheetNames = ["Foglio1"];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 
sheet.getLastColumn());
range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
});
}

function add24toH(){
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Foglio1');
var rg=sh.getDataRange();
var vA=rg.getValues();
for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
vA[i][2]+=24;//H
}
rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Good job. You did a lot of that on your own. So on your next question most users would appreciate it if you could do a much of that sort of thing on your own before you come here to ask a question.  Now that you have them altogether try to write them as one function.  Give it a try, I bet you can do it.  But if you have trouble come back here with your attempted code.

Comment: Tanks Cooper!! All done!!! I posted also the code for merge in all-in-one all my functions. Bye

Answer (score 0):

This code merge all script in oll-in-one

```
function onEdit() {
myFunction1(); // call function #1
myFunction2(); // call function #2
}
```

Comment: That's works.  I often due this sort of thing when I edit website hitlists because it's easier for me to make minor changes in sub functions rather than to have to mess with one big function.